# Deleting $n$ points from a connected space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a space such that for any subset $S \subset X$ with finite cardinality $n$, the subspace $X \setminus S$ has exactly $n+1$ connected components, each of which is homeomorphic to $X$. Is there such a space $X$ which is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If we remove the "each of which is homemorphic to $X$" condition, the long line is such a space.

Comment: Is $n$ fixed for this problem?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip It suffices to take $n=1$.

Comment: $(0,1) \times (0, 1)$ does not work, but I think $(0, 1) \times [0, 1]$ does.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen If we remove one point in the center, the result is connected.

Comment: @AlexBecker: I was not thinking of the usual topology but of the lexicographic order topology, as in the original question.

Comment: @AlexBecker  I agree that it suffices to solve it for $n=1$. Conceivably you could find a space where it works for $n=2$ and not $n=1$ though, or am I missing something?

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen: I agree. I think $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ works with the order topology.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen: Removing a point $\langle a, b \rangle$ (with $b> 0$) from $(0,1)\times[0,1]$ (with the lex order topology) results in one connected component being homeomorphic to $((0,1]\times[0,1]) \setminus\{\langle 1,1 \rangle\}$ (with the lex order topology). These are not homeomorphic, as you can remove a point from the latter resulting in one connected component homeomorphic to the real line, which is not possible in the former.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen: oops, I forgot that $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ has infinitely many components! So, yeah, I guess neither of those examples works.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Sorry, I forgot that condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a bit of a cheap example.   Consider the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ described in [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/736365/8348). Since the topology is finer than the usual topology, the removal of any point disconnects the space, and it is relatively easy to see that there are two connected components, each of which is homeomorphic to the original space.